# foreach and if statement to display custom taxonomies

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to display custom taxonomies but if there are none to display a message.

Here is as far as I have gotten:

```
<?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'machine-features' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ($term) {
            echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
        } else {
            echo "Contact us for details";
        }
    }
?>
```

It works perfectly when there are features added but when empty I get the following error:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I'm new to php so apologies if this is a crazy basic question - I searched for an answer and tried various permutations but nothing worked!

Thanks a million for any help! 
O

Comment: use `if(count($terms) > 0)` before foreach loop

Comment: Thanks @Saty for reply but still getting error - here is what I did: '        <?php
         $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'machine-features' );
          if(count($terms) > 0) {
           foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
           }
          } else {
           echo "Contact us for details";
          } 

        ?> '

Comment: show code of function `get_the_terms()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'machine-features' );
        if(!empty( $terms ) )  {    
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>'; } 
            } else {
                echo "Contact us for details";
            }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Rohit Padma - your answer helped me fix it - I just needed to rearrange the if-statement a bit and it works perfectly :-)